# Seemingly arbitrary result when multiplying complex numbers

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I'm trying to understand how complex numbers get multiplied. when I multiply two numbers it always seems to give me an arbitrary amount. for example,
`complex(10,9)*complex(11,13)` equals `complex(-7,229)`and `complex(10,1)*complex(10,2)` equals `complex(98,30)`. is there a mathematical way to figure out 2 complex numbers multiplied and if so, what is is it?

Answer (score 2):

The result is not arbitrary, it is following the definition of [complex multiplication](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexMultiplication.html):

For example if you have

```
x = a + j * b
y = c + j * d
```

then the expression for multiplication is

```
x * y = (a * c - b * d) + j (a * d + b * c)
```

For your example `complex(10,9) * complex(11,13)` that would evaluate to

```
(10 * 11 - 9 * 13) + j * (10 * 13 + 9 * 11)
(-7 + 229j)
```

which is exactly what Python shows

```
>>> complex(10,9) * complex(11,13)
(-7+229j)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Complex number multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Multiplication) operates in this way:

```
(a + ib) * (c + id) = a * c + a * id + ib * c + ib * id
                    = a * c - b * d + i(a * d + b * c)
```

So, in Python, the result is like this:

```
complex(a, b) * complex(c, d) = complex(a * c - b * d, a * d + b * c)
```

Example:

```
complex(10, 9) * complex(11, 13) = complex(10 * 11 - 9 * 13, 10 * 13 + 9 * 11)
                                 = complex(-7, 227)
```

Comment: You have a typo in your example. It should be complex(10*11-9*13,10*13+9*11)

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 complex numbers, the first `a + bj`, and the second `c + dj`, then the product `(a + bj) * (c + dj) = a*c - b*d + (a*d + b*c)j`. The way to think about it is that j is equal to the square root of -1, so j*j = -1, and then just multiply out the brackets as normal. See below:

```py
a, b = 10, 9
c, d = 11, 13


print(complex(a, b)*complex(c, d))
print(a*c - b*d, a*d + b*c)
```

Output:

```
(-7+229j)
-7 229
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to understand complex number multiplication is geometrically. We can think of complex numbers as two dimensional vectors, things with a length and direction. Then when multiplying a complex number with length r and direction a by another with length s and direction b, you get a complex number with length r*s and direction a+b, i.e. a complex number with length r and direction a acts on others by multiplication by scaling them by r and rotating them through a.
If you work out the lengths and directions of your (10,9) and (11,13) and combine them as above, you will get the length and direction of (-7,229)